# Resource not available problem

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jersey

I get a HTTP Status 404 - Requested resource (/Fun/hello) is not available.
I am running Tomcat 7.0, Jersey 1.8, Java 1.6, Eclipse Helios 2.
I am working from a tutorial by Lars Vogel.

As far as I can tell, the resource is being loaded:

```
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class bighello.Hello
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> 
  <display-name>Fun</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>bighello</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

In the `web.xml` , you only map one URL pattern , which is `/rest/*` to call  the servlet.

But now , your request URL is `/Fun/hello` , which does not match any URL patterns you defined in the `web.xml` , so it returns `HTTP Status 404`

In fact, refer to section 3.4 of your mentioned [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) , you should test your REST service under: `http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello`.